# Estimative of Ricci curvature from secctional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ a riemannian manifold such that the secctional curvature of $M$ is greater than or equal $-k$, i.e, $Sec_{M}\geq -k$ where $k$ is a non-negative real number. There exists a hope of an estimative of the ricci curvature of $M$ as $Ric_{M}\geq something$?

Edit: Let $p \in M$ , and $\{z_{1},z_{2},\dots, z_{n}\}$ an orthonormal basis in $T_{p}M$. Now, if $X=z_{1}$ , the Ricci curvature in the direction $X$ is defined by

$Ric(X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} <R(X,z_{i})X,z_{i}>$

Comment: So, what is the definition of $\text{Ric}_M$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin post Edited

Comment: Better to use $X$ as one element of your orthonormal basis. Now what does your sectional curvature bound tell you about the $n-1$ terms in the sum?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, since the Ricci curvature is the sum of $n-1$ sectional curvatures of the planes passing trought the point $p$ and in the whole manifold $Sec_{M}\geq -k$ follow that $Ric_{M}\geq -k.(n-1)$?

Comment: Looks good to me.